# how to drop administrative user in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c

I am not able to drop a user created by me which has administrative rights.

I am running below command:

```
drop user GOVIND CASCADE;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28014: cannot drop administrative users
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

set _oracle_script to TRUE and execute drop command as below.

```
alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;
```

Session altered

```
drop user APEX_050000 cascade;
```

User dropped.